# Recording audio mic in with Powershell

Tags: powershell, audio

How can I record audio with the Mic In line with Powershell?

I am trying using the sound recorder, but even though I can open the program, I can't make it record and save a file.  Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 : Yes, in cmd this works:
SoundRecorder /FILE filename.filetype /DURATION hhhh:mm:ss.
But when I try in powershell, no file is generated.  The sound recorder icon is shown in the task bar (like if it was recording), but no file is generated.  
When I try this in cmd, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work by copying the .exe in the working directory and with the following code:

```
$here = $PSScriptRoot
$path = $here+"\SoundRecorder.exe"
$filepath = $here+"\test2.wma"
$arg1 = "/FILE $filepath /DURATION 0000:00:10"
& $path $arg1
```